# Receiving 401 'Unauthorized' when working with Storyblok CMS API

Tags: curl, nuxt.js, content-management-system, storyblok

I am struggling to get started with Storyblok CMS. I have been following some of the tutorials on the Interwebs, e.g., Nuxt JS with Storyblok, etc., but I cannot seem to successfully call the API without receiving a 401 'Unauthorized' exception.

At first, I thought it was my code so I tried:

```
curl "https://api.storyblok.com/v2/cdn/stories?token=MYTOKEN" -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

but that didn't work either.  Double checked my token, etc.  I must be missing something.  I am on the non-paying Community plan right now.

Comment: What sort of access tokens have you created? All preview on any public ones too? The docs say that a 401 suggests a problem with the access token so lets start there. :)

Answer (score 5):

It's likely the region you deployed to - if the US, the host is `api-us.storyblok.com`. When using and initializing the JS API give it the option `region: "us"`.

Some sample code provided by a helpful commenter:

```
const apiOptions = { accessToken: '<YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>', region: 'us' }
const storyblok = new StoryblokClient(apiOptions)
```

Comment: This ended up being my issue. Was pretty frustrating that [it wasn't neatly documented anywhere](https://www.storyblok.com/tp/index-storyblok-algolia).

```
const apiOptions = {
    accessToken: '<YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>',
    region: 'us'
}

const storyblok = new StoryblokClient(apiOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but I found that the issue was that the api wasn't designed to respond to the format of my request.

If you're like me then the issue is that you didn't specify a story in the route of the url. So your request should look more like

`curl "https://api.storyblok.com/v2/cdn/stories/home?token=MYTOKEN" -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json"`

where I've added "/home" to the url as an example of a story.